# Python script not working properly on excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, loops, iteration

My python code is not working properly on excel file.

I wrote a python code to get an excel sheet, URLs from the sheet and extract the version number from URLs. Create a copy of the sheet with an additional column 'latest version', compare the extracted number with the number in the sheet, if they are same, return 'same' in latest version, if not, return the extracted version number, else return empty string.
It is returning values to only 1st 2 lines, then skipping a lot of links and then returning values again. I tried changing the order of the links tp see if there's any issue with the links, it did the same, returned values to the ones on the 1st 2 positions and then skipped.

Here is the script where it copies data from the source sheet, iteration is started from the 2nd row because 1st row contains headers:

```
`for row in source_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    url = row[0].value
    version = row[1].value
    extracted_version = extract_version(url, version)
    new_row = ['', '', '']
    new_row[0] = url 
    new_row[1] = version
    new_row[2] = extracted_version
    new_sheet.append(new_row`)
```

PS: making little changes in the above code sometimes returns latest version value for none of the links and sometimes for some additional links, but not for all.

Comment: Which library are you using to open the excel file?

Comment: i'm using openpyxl

Comment: When you say "extract the version number from URLs" do you mean that your parsing/extracting a version number from the values of Column 1? Or are there two columns: "URLs" & "Version Numbers"? input and output examples would help clarify, because it's not clear if the issue is in the code or the data itself.

Comment: Inputs are two columns, 1: URLs, 2: Current Versions. 
It visits URLs from column 1, does HTML  parsing to extract version numbers, compares the extracted versions with the current versions present in the column 2 of input file. The output is an excel file with an additional column (3) 'Latest Version' in which it returns 'Same' if both are same, and if different, it returns the extracted version. PS: the links are all working and have the version number information in similar HTML tags.